# Best practice for keeping named constants in code and database reference tables in sync?

Tags: database

It's generally best practice to use named constants in place of magic numbers, but it sure is tedious and error prone keeping a database reference table and a file of named constants in sync. Is there some easy way to keep these two sources for this info in sync, or am I overlooking an obvious design enhancement?

In case my question isn't clear, here's an example. I have a reference table with 2 columns:

```
UserStatus
----------
UserStatusID
UserStatus
```

So this table associates a UsersStatusID 1 with the UserStatus 'Active'. The User table relies on this table to normalize UserStatuses.

So when querying for a User's status from code, I have two options:

```
SELECT UserStatusID FROM Users WHERE UserStatus = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT UserStatusID FROM Users WHERE UserStatus = ACTIVE_USER_STATUS_ID
```

Best practice is to use the latter so the meaning of the number 1 is clear. But this means I have to maintain a complete list of valid UserStatusID's in my UserStatus table and in my code. How do I avoid having to keep both the DB reference table and my constants file updated? I'm using a centralized constants file so there's only 1 place I have to update for my code, but is there a way to avoid having to update a constants file at all when a new status in introduced?

I have one idea: Schedule a script to run once a day to populate a constants file via a query of the reference tables in the db. Is this the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your constants in the database.  Query them as needed.

If performance is a problem, then load *all* of the constants at application startup into an internal data structure, then use that throughout the application.

So your code example would be:

```
SELECT UserStatusID
FROM Users 
WHERE UserStatus = (
                   SELECT INTEGER_VALUE
                   from DB_CONSTANTS
                   WHERE CONSTANT_ID = 'ACTIVE_USER_STATUS_ID'
                   )
```

Or, if you use an internal structure, it would be more like this:

```
SELECT UserStatusID
FROM Users 
WHERE UserStatus = g_Constants.ActiveUserStatusID;
```